# How to randomly answer prompts with specific characters in Bash?

Tags: bash

I want to do something similar to the [yes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) package. Which is often times used to answer "y" to all prompts.

Imagine there is a program (script_that_prompts.sh) giving thousands of prompts.

```
for ((n=0;n<3000;n++))
do 
    read -p "input 0|1|2|y:" ans; 
    # do something with ans
    # ...
done
```

---

**I need a command that randomly picks an answer from the list ['0', '1', '2', 'y'], and answer the prompt for each prompt from the loop.**

I have read the manual of the yes package, and it seems like it only accepts one string (and options). It can only answer with one and the same string.

I have trying piping multiple yes together without luck.

---

The desired way to do this is:

```
<command> ... | bash script_that_prompts.sh
```

I know one possibility is to run a script in background as a job, and listens to the output, but wouldn't that introduce unnecessary complexity?

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how to do this properly?

Comment: What is the purpose of `read` if a random element is to be chosen from a list?

Comment: That is the code to generate thousands of prompts. Essentially an extracted code from script_that_prompts.sh. I want give input to the prompts created by that script, using a command similar to the yes package.

Comment: The entered value isn't used, so why do you need to issue a prompt? For instance, why not this code printing random elements from an array without prompting: `items=(0 1 2 y); for ((i = 0; i < 10;++i)); do echo "${items[RANDOM % ${#items[*]}]}"; done`

Comment: This code is a simplified version. The entered values are used, but just not shown in the question, because that is not the point. The point is on the command that I want to use to enter values to the prompts. "script_that_prompts.py" is actually a Makefile, which prompts, and I need to enter values. I will edit the question to clarify this further.

Comment: `${items[RANDOM % ${#items[*]}]}` picks an element randomly from the array `items`. Define the array as `items=(0 1 2 y)` before calling that.

Comment: Okay thank you, now I understand. It works. Please create an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a command that randomly picks an answer from the list ['0',
> '1', '2', 'y']

Just assign elements into an array, `items=(0 1 2 y)`, and pick one of them randomly by `${items[RANDOM % ${#items[*]}]}`. `%` is the remainder operator. `${#items[*]}` expands to the element count of the array `items`, which is `4` for this sample. The `4` could be hard-coded like `${items[RANDOM % 4]}`, but the form I used works for every element count of the array. `RANDOM % ${#items[*]}` generates randomly a number between `0` (inclusive) and element count of the array (exclusive), which is used for the array index. It generates one of the `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`, since the element count is `4` for this sample. `RANDOM` is a `bash` variable which gives a random integer between 0 and 32767 (both inclusive) each time it is referenced. `${items[RANDOM % ${#items[*]}]}` access the array element with the index randomly generated.

Note: Bash's `$RANDOM` shouldn't be used when any precision is required.